# What BLE device has services with UUID F002 and/or F003?

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Among the various officially registered Bluetooth device services, which are listed on the Bluetooth.org website, there is no mention of F002 or F003. But I recently was scanning for BLE in public and some unnamed device had these two services. Does anyone here know what device uses F002 or F003? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Services in BLE can be **adopted** or **custom**. They have UUIDs that are 128bit long but are usually identified by their 16-bit offset:-

- **Adopted** services are those listed by the Bluetooth SIG as
  standard Bluetooth UUIDs. They're given a unique number and you have
  probably already seen them [here](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx?_ga=1.50499553.952158773.1458165233). Examples of those include the
  Heart Rate (offset 180D), Health Thermometer (offset 1809), Battery
  (offset 180F), etc. Those UUIDs are universal and if you see 180D
  anywhere it should mean that it's the heart rate service.
- **Custom** UUIDs on the other hand are undefined and in many cases can be just randomly generated. F002 is not an identified offset and therefore can belong to anyone using it for any random service.

I do remember coming across TI sensor tags with a similar UUID so it's worth investigating if you have any of those lying around.

A good read of UUIDs and BLE in general can be found here:-

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html